# c# calulcation logic

Tags: c#, logic

i am looking to put together some logic to look at a particular number and based on a simple calulcation tell me what another number is. Example - lets say that i have a string of characters and each 50 characters will increment an integer by 1. so if i have 0 - 49 chars, counter = 1, if i have 50-99 chars, counter = 2, if i have 100 - 149 chars, counter = 3.

i thought i could do this by converting everything to type int but that doesnt work as sometimes it will round down when it should always round up - i.e. (int)(charCount / 50).

Im wondering if i have to use the modulus operator. Any suggestions?

Comment: ITs not at all clear what you are trying to do or what question you are asking.  Perhaps a more concrete example?

Comment: without getting into specifics, a user will enter in a field with a string of text. the text will always have a value between 1 and infinity.

the text needs to fit into specific areas that can only contain a certain number of characters.

I need to work out how many areas i need based on the users input.

In my example each area can contain 50 characters.

Does this make more sense?

Comment: sorry the text's length will always have a value between 1 and infinity

Comment: you can think of each area like an array - but thats not what im trying to work with here.

Comment: A good example may be SMS's... you can only have 160 chars in an SMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this exact example, you can just increment the counter after your division, so:

```
int counter = (int)(stringToCheck.Length / 50) + 1
```